# Bash move * to subfolder fail: cannot move to a subdirectory of itself

Tags: bash

I have a folder with several files that I want to move to a subfolder:

```
mkdir subfolder
mv ./* subfolder
```

But when I do this, I get:

`mv: cannot move 'subfolder' to a subdirectory of itself`

How can I simply avoid this?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call this a "failure", exactly. Everything else was still moved, no?

Comment: Just suppress the _stderr_ from the command, it probably moved all the files, `mv ./* subfolder 2>/dev/null`

Comment: Yeah right, but apparently the command exited with status `0`

Comment: I mean a non-zero code

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using `extglob` you can do this:

```
shopt -s extglob

mv !(subfolder) subfolder
```

Glob expression `!(subfolder)` will match everything except `subfolder`.

Comment: how to write mv !(subfolder) subfolder in bash...
 it say expected command near "("

Comment: Make sure you are using extglob

Comment: This does not move hidden files starting with .

Comment: For turn on dotglob option

Answer (score 9):

Was this on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)?

If so, Windows recognizes the directory Jerry as equal to directory jerry, and WSL follows certain Windows rules for compatibility.

If you want to rename the directory Jerry to jerry, you could do the following:

```
mv Jerry placeholder_name
mv placeholder_name jerry
```

Answer (score 8):

There is an easy solution

```
mv * subfolder | mkdir subfolder
```

It will move all the files from the folder to the subfolder without any errors.

Comment: Although it trows an same error, it gets the job done !

Answer (score 2):

I went for:

`find . -maxdepth 1 -not -name subfolder -exec mv -t subfolder {} +`

though I still find the syntax very unreadable...

Comment: add `-mindepth 1` to exclude `.`

Answer (score 2):

Umm I had a similar problem. Took me a couple of tries! But I ended up with

```
mkdir ../subfolder
mv * ../subfolder
mv ../subfolder .
```